# Does anyone recognise following (USB,HID?) encoding method?

Tags: cryptography, usb, hash-functions

Im reverse engineering a Keyborard RGB LED Control Software and there is a Library called "HidServ.dll" that seems to be the interface between the Keyboard and the Software. Every Function of that Library is called like this for example:
(This is my translation of the assembler code, the function names are not the real ones)

```
int arghash1 = ArgHash(0, arg1, arg1len);
int arghash2 = ArgHash(ahash1, arg2, arg2len);
int arghash3 = ArgHash(ahash2, arg3, arg3len);

int count = HidServ.RequestGetDeviceCount(arg1, arg2, arg3, arghash3, 0);
```

It seems to compute some kind of hash of the first 3 arguments. Heres the the ArgHash function:

```
public unsafe static int ArgHash(int startvalue, byte* argumentPtr, int length)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        startvalue += cryptarray[*(argumentPtr + i)];
    }

    return startvalue;
}
```

So basically the function adds together the values of cryptarray on the indexes of the values of each byte of an argument.

The cryptarray is 256 bytes long and looks like this:

```
private static byte[] cryptarray = new byte[]
    {
        0xFD, 0x86, 0xD1, 0xCA, 0xDB, 0xD5, 0xCC, 0x5E, 0x02, 0x0E, 0xE0, 0xB6, 0xA9, 0xF7, 0x6D, 0xA8,
        0xE2, 0x77, 0x0D, 0x09, 0xFE, 0x3D, 0x9A, 0x0B, 0x28, 0x85, 0xDC, 0xC3, 0x52, 0x48, 0x00, 0x01,
        0xBE, 0x79, 0x51, 0xFF, 0xB7, 0x83, 0xA2, 0x14, 0x10, 0x20, 0x82, 0xED, 0xD9, 0x16, 0x43, 0x4F,
        0x1C, 0x90, 0xC6, 0xD8, 0xBF, 0x56, 0x0C, 0x5C, 0xAA, 0xD3, 0x95, 0x0A, 0x73, 0x21, 0x67, 0xEB,
        0xDD, 0xA4, 0x8E, 0x26, 0xB8, 0xF2, 0xE8, 0x25, 0x1F, 0x59, 0x66, 0x1D, 0x61, 0x1E, 0xBB, 0xE5,
        0x99, 0xC5, 0x8F, 0xBC, 0xA6, 0xEE, 0x33, 0xB0, 0x53, 0x89, 0xD0, 0x2E, 0xC7, 0x88, 0xCE, 0x45,
        0x4C, 0xB2, 0x23 ,0x76, 0xB1, 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xCD, 0xFC, 0x06, 0x19, 0x29, 0x37, 0x98, 0x7E, 0x22,
        0xA7, 0xDA, 0x32, 0x60, 0x08, 0x8C, 0x24, 0x8A, 0x84, 0xC4, 0x4A, 0x12, 0x70, 0xB9, 0x49, 0x74,
        0x30, 0xE1, 0x2A, 0x4E, 0x2D, 0x4B, 0x7C, 0x5F, 0x71, 0xC8, 0x04, 0x41, 0x81, 0x63, 0x3F, 0xF3,
        0x6C, 0xF1, 0x8D, 0x9B, 0x6E, 0xAD, 0x6F, 0xB3, 0x38, 0x54, 0x2C, 0x87, 0x64, 0x7B, 0x0F, 0xC9,
        0xFA, 0xC0, 0xDF, 0xFB, 0xF4, 0xD7, 0x07, 0x92, 0x69, 0xC2, 0x7D, 0x1B, 0x80, 0x68, 0xB4, 0x15,
        0x47, 0x50, 0x57, 0x39, 0x3B, 0x2B, 0x5A, 0xD4, 0x13, 0x6B, 0xB5, 0x3E, 0x1A, 0xE3, 0x9D, 0xF9,
        0x17, 0x35, 0x46, 0x78, 0x75, 0xA5, 0x6A, 0x55, 0x9C, 0x4D, 0xEC, 0xA3, 0x36, 0x31, 0xE9, 0xF6,
        0x62, 0xEF, 0x40, 0xC1, 0xBD, 0x94, 0x3A, 0x96, 0x11, 0x97, 0x7F, 0x72, 0x9E, 0x7A, 0xBA, 0xE6,
        0xCF, 0xAF, 0x18, 0x44, 0xEA, 0x03, 0x9F, 0x2F, 0x93, 0xCB, 0x8B, 0xD6, 0xE4, 0x58, 0x5D, 0xA1,
        0x27, 0xE7, 0xAC, 0x91, 0xAB, 0x34, 0x3C, 0x05, 0xAE, 0x5B, 0x42, 0x65, 0xA0, 0xF5, 0xD2, 0xDE
    };
```

Does anyone know which Encryption algorythm this is? Is it the USB CRC5 Algorythm?

Comment: `cryptarray` looks like an sbox. `startvalue` is just sum of all the lookups in `cryptarray` - substitution of all bytes.

Comment: I suspect its calculating some kind of checksum, but i dont really know which kind

Comment: Its not any "kind of checksum". Its just the sum of substituted bytes. Simple sum.

Comment: The sum has to have a purpose. And since its a HID library, the receiving device may also calculate the sum from the the received data and compares it to the given sum. In this case it would be called a checksum. I dont know for sure if its really a checksum (that's why I'm asking here) but to reject my assumptions without any explaination is not very helpful.